# Loading multiple GCS files into one BigQuery Table

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, airflow

I have a folder in GCS that gets filled with a one specific file everyday. File_Name_(ingestion_date).csv. Currently there are about 70 files one for each day going back 70 days, I would like to start ingesting all of these into a single BigQuery table. They all have the exact same schema. Is it possible to use 1 GCStoBigQueryOperator task to ingest them all at the same time?

```
load_csv_to_ingestion = GCSToBigQueryOperator(
        task_id=f"load_csv_to_ingestion_{environment}",
        bucket=landing_bucket,
        source_objects=[f"{folder_name}/{file_name}_*"],
        destination_project_dataset_table=f"{ingestion_project_id}.{INGESTION_DATASET}.{file_name}",
        schema_fields=schema,
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
        create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        field_delimiter=",",
        skip_leading_rows=1,
        allow_jagged_rows=True,
        autodetect=False,
        dag=dag,
    )
```

Where for source_objects I use * to get all the ingestion dates.
source_objects=[f"{folder_name}/{file_name}_*"],

for example files are named:

file_name_05-21-2023.csv,

file_name_05-22-2023.csv,

file_name_05-23-2023.csv

Is this possible?

Comment: Are you going to re-ingest daily?  Because depending on how you're using the data downstream, it might just be easier to define it as an external table, which you can use a wildcard for.